# Is it possible to join multiple tables with one to many relations to the primary table without duplicated records?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Person Table

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
+----+------+
```

Car Table

```
+----+----------+
| id | car      |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Audi     |
|  1 | BMW      |
|  1 | Mercedes |
+----+----------+
```

Credit_Card Table

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | bank            |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Scotiabank      |
|  1 | Bank of America |
+----+-----------------+
```

the id in Person table is the foreign key for the other two, I wonder if there is a way to join these tables together without showing duplicated records like this:

```
+----+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | name | car      | bank            |
+----+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | John | Audi     | Scotiabank      |
|NULL| NULL | BMW      | Bank of America|
|NULL| NULL | Mercedes | NULL            |
+----+------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: But the result set is surely meaningless?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but you shouldn't.  Instead, I'l recommend putting all the values in one row:

```
select p.id, p.name,
       (select group_concat(c.car)
        from car c
        where c.id = p.id
       ) as cars,
       (select group_concat(b.bank)
        from banks b
        where b.id = p.id
       ) as banks
from person p ;
```

Why shouldn't you put the result in multiple rows as you specify?  Well, it is definitely possible.  However, the columns in a row should "related" to each other (this is much of what the "relational" in "relational algebra" is talking about).  When you replace the first columns with `NULL`, then they no longer have any relationship to the rest of the columns.  Similarly, the values in the last two columns have nothing to do with each other.

Plus, I'm guessing that the above pretty much does what you really want.

Comment: Thank you very much! that is really helpful!